# Filter a list of items based on URL path

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a component list of items in React. I want to filter these items based on URL path. For example if URL is something like below line I want items to be filtered by `date` attribute, with value `2010` :

```
http://localhost:3000/?filter='date'&value='2010'
```

As I'm so new in React I couldn't find any easy-to-understand answer, Is there any source I can learn about this question?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is the way to do it, but I think your approach is incorrect from the beginning. Please add more detail about your scenario, why you need that feature ?

Comment: @thelonglqd
It is asked in project to save filters in URL so that it is not vanished by refreshing the page.

Comment: do you use `react-router` and `react-router-dom` ?

Comment: @thelonglqd react-router-dom

Comment: If my solution resolve your issue, please help to mark it as accepted answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `useLocation` hook to get the query params string from URL and then use `query-string` lib to parse the query params string to object. Like below:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import queryString from 'query-string';

const App = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('query params object: ', queryString.parse(location.search));
  }, [location])
}

export default App;
```

**NOTE**: Please be aware that the number of characters on a browser URL is limited, find the best solution that fits your need.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can get data in url in this manner:

```
const [currentUrl, setCurrentUrl] = useState()
const currentUrl = window.location.href.split('/')
```